# "Failed to open stream: Permission denied" only absolute path, relative path works

Tags: php, permissions

I'm facing a curious problem, if I try to read a file using the relative path everything works, if I use and absolute path it throws a "Permission denied"

Works:

```
include './test.php';
```

Permission denied:

```
include '/var/www/test.php';
```

I've tried of course via command line and paths are correct.
I have a vague memory of reading something about permissions of parent folders in case of absolute path, but I can't find it back.

Comment: try `include './var/www/test.php';`

Comment: I need to use absolute paths

Comment: then consider using ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ./var/www/test.php)

Comment: hem, the result would be '/var/www/./var/www/test.php' it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: open_basedir settings?